# How can I kill a stuck LXC container?

Tags: lxc

I have a new unprivileged LXC container that I just cannot seem to stop. `lxc-stop -n dl` hangs. `lxc-stop -k --nolock -n dl` hangs. `lxc-ls` hangs. `lxc-attach -n dl` hangs. Nothing works on this container.

I have restarted `lcxfs`. All that did was upset a privileged container. This is what the current processes for this container look like (from the host).

```
lxc-start,24434
  └─systemd,24446 --system --deserialize 9
      ├─agetty,25258 --noclear --keep-baud console 115200 38400 9600 vt220
      ├─agetty,25846 --noclear --keep-baud pts/1 115200 38400 9600 vt220
      ├─agetty,25878 --noclear --keep-baud pts/3 115200 38400 9600 vt220
      ├─agetty,25906 --noclear --keep-baud pts/2 115200 38400 9600 vt220
      ├─agetty,25934 --noclear --keep-baud pts/0 115200 38400 9600 vt220
      ├─rsyslogd,26016 -n
      │   ├─{rsyslogd},26043
      │   └─{rsyslogd},26044
      └─systemd-journal,25962
```

And the process states:

```
$ ps aux | grep -P '24434|24446|25258|25846|25878|25906|25934|25934|26016|26043|26044|25962'
oli      24434  0.0  0.0  43400  3552 ?        Ss   10:56   0:00 [lxc monitor] /home/oli/.local/share/lxc dl
100000   24446  0.0  0.1  36896  4972 ?        Ss   10:56   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 9
100000   25258  0.0  0.0  15676  2504 pts/0    Ss+  10:56   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear --keep-baud console 115200 38400 9600 vt220
100000   25846  0.0  0.0  15676  2496 pts/1    Ss+  11:33   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear --keep-baud pts/1 115200 38400 9600 vt220
100000   25878  0.0  0.0  15676  2380 pts/3    Ss+  11:33   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear --keep-baud pts/3 115200 38400 9600 vt220
100000   25906  0.0  0.0  15676  2416 pts/2    Ss+  11:33   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear --keep-baud pts/2 115200 38400 9600 vt220
100000   25934  0.0  0.0  15676  2332 pts/0    Ss+  11:33   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear --keep-baud pts/0 115200 38400 9600 vt220
100000   25962  0.0  0.0  35256  3500 ?        Ss   11:33   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
100104   26016  0.0  0.0 182640  3244 ?        Ssl  11:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
```

Answer (score 4):

Force killing the container's `systemd` process worked for me.

In your example,

```
kill -9 24446
```

Answer (score 0):

I keep this command line around to quickly kill all processes with a very high UID (which are in my container):

```
ps -ef | grep "^100[0-9][0-9][0-9]" | tr -s " " | cut -f2 -d " " | xargs -I {} kill -9 {}
```

Then I can use `lxc-start` again.

I also found out that I have less problems with `lxc-stop` when I use `lxc-start -d` (in background mode) and then connect using `lxc-attach` or `ssh`.